# Cygwin on windows 2000

Tags: cygwin, windows-2000

I need to install cygwin on a windows 2000 machine. I already found a good setup.exe, but none of the downloads or mirrors seem to work, so where can I find the files to manually install Cygwin 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install an old version as current one does not support Windows 2000 anymore.

The place to look is `The Cygwin Time Machine` website:
http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html